# What's a good ML model/technique for breaking down large documents/text/HTML into segments?

Tags: parsing, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'd like to break down HTML documents into small chunks of information. With sources like Wikipedia articles (as an example) this is reasonably easy to do, without machine learning, because the content is structured in a highly predictable way.

When working with something like a converted Word Doc or a Blog post, the HTML is a bit more unpredictable. For example, sometimes there are no DIVs, more than one H1 in a document, or no Headers at all etc.

I'm trying to figure out a decent/reliable way of automatically putting content breaks into my content, in order to break it down into chunks of an acceptable size.

I've had a little dig around for existing trained models for this application but I couldn't find anything off-the-shelf. I've considered training my own model, but I'm not confident of the best way to structure the training data. One option I've considered in relation to training data is providing a sample of where section breaks are numerically likely to exist within a document but I don't think that's the best possible approach...

How would you approach this problem?

---

*P.s. I'm currently using Tensorflow but happy to go down a different path.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the GROBID library quite robust for different input documents (since it's based on ML models trained on a large variety of documents). The standard model parses input PDF documents into structured XML/TEI encoded files, which are much easier to deal with. https://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Introduction/

If your inputs are HTML documents the library also offers the possibility to train your own models. Have a look at: https://grobid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Training-the-models-of-Grobid/